# Open cl.exe from C# application

Tags: c#

I need to compile a C++ program from My C# application. In there I need to open the cl.exe when I press button. Can anyone give me some sample code.

Comment: What have you tried? Executing cl.exe is no different to executing any other process...

Comment: Sorry i couldn't get it.

Comment: http://www.csharp-station.com/howto/processstart.aspx

Comment: cl.exe requires a different environment to run correctly.  This is setup by using a batch file provided by Visual Studio.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/84404/using-visual-studios-cl-from-a-normal-command-line for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string filePath = "c:\program files\xyz\cl.exe";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filePath);
```

Comment: Hi, When i use this methode it will display the following error. how can i pass the pile name for CL.exe 

System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception was unhandled
  Message="The system cannot find the file specified"
  Source="System"
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  NativeErrorCode=2
  StackTrace:

Comment: Put the full path of CL.exe, e.g. "c:\program files\xyz\cl.exe"

Comment: This is not the correct answer, cl.exe requires mspdb100.dll (and a few other items) to be in your %PATH%.  I've outlined the real solution below.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open some exe you can use:`Process.Start("cl.exe");`

Comment: Hi, When i use this methode it will display the following error. how can i pass the pile name for CL.exe System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception was unhandled Message="The system cannot find the file specified" Source="System" ErrorCode=-2147467259 NativeErrorCode=2 StackTrace

Comment: you need to mention the proper path of the exe.

Answer (score 0):

cl.exe requires DLL's that aren't in the %PATH%.  You need to execute the correct batch for the architecture (x86 versus 64 bit).  This will update your environment so you can launch cl.exe correctly.

x86 is located here (VS2010):

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat

I currently launch the command console, execute the batch, then launch the compile on my temp file.

```
string tempPath = Path.GetTempPath();
string tempName = "scrap_" + random.Next();

Process compiler = new Process();

compiler.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
compiler.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = tempPath;
compiler.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
compiler.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
compiler.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

compiler.Start();
compiler.StandardInput.WriteLine("\"" + @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat" + "\"");
compiler.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"cl.exe /nologo /EHsc " + tempName + ".cpp");
compiler.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"exit");
string output = compiler.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
compiler.WaitForExit();
Debug.Write(output);
compiler.Close();
```

I'm currently looking at launching vcvars32.bat directly, but I'm not sure if it updates the environment for my C# app correctly.  I'll update you if I get it working.

Also, make sure you read and understand the accepted answer on this thread: [ProcessStartInfo hanging on "WaitForExit"? Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139593/processstartinfo-hanging-on-waitforexit-why)