# How do I compile C++ file a SINGLE file using the command line on the Windows command line

Tags: .net, c++, compiler-construction, compilation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using Visual Studio's 'cl' from a normal command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84404/using-visual-studios-cl-from-a-normal-command-line)

I have .net framework installed.

*I did search before posting. I searched for `compile c++ command line windows`*.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/84404/using-visual-studios-cl-from-a-normal-command-line I dunno if you need anything special to get .NET stuff to work though.

Comment: Do you wish to compile C# code or C++ code?

Answer (score 2):

For starters, you need a compiler.

then you run the compiler, passing the file to it as an argument, eg `cl myfile.cpp` (you may want to pass some compiler options in there too, but which ones depend on which compiler you use - visual studio's, or gcc or Intels, etc).

MS has a brief [starter guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235639%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for you, but [this one for gcc](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~beechung/ref/gcc-intro.html) is probably better as its describes all the steps involved.