# How Can Be Used the Command Line of Developer Command Prompt in Vim on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, vim

I have *Visual Studio Express for Windows Desktop* installed on this laptop and I can compile a C++ source file with the command `cl /EHsc filename.cpp` and a C++ program that uses .NET classes with the command `cl /clr filenameclr.cpp` on the command line of **Developer Command Prompt for VS2012** using this instructions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235639.aspx

How can I be able to compile in Vim *(text editor)* on Microsoft Windows with those commands? `:cl /EHsc filename.cpp` and `:cl /clr filenameclr.cpp` does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to setup your `PATH`, `INCLUDE` and `LIB` environment variables.

You could do that by running `D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat` (or wherever it is located on your installation) in the same prompt you're running vim, or even manually setting these environment variables (here is a list of all values for VS2008 and Windows SDK: [Using Visual Studio's 'cl' from a normal command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84404/using-visual-studios-cl-from-a-normal-command-line)).

However, you just can't run the `bat` file from vim directly, because it will open another Prompt, so the environment variables will be set only for that new prompt. The other option is just to create bat file which you can put it inside your `PATH`, for example `cvim`:

```
call "D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim74\gvim.exe"
```

After that, typing `cvim.bat` will get you in the environment ready for running `:! cl /EHsc %`