# Run cl.exe from cmd

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have installed `Visual Studio Community 2017` with C++. I wanted to use its compiler from cmd. I am able to use it from `Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017` but I am unable to use it from normal cmd. I have tried running `vsvarsall.exe` by `right click-> run as administrator`. But nothing happens. Seems like I have to set environment variables manually.
Whenever I try to run the command

`cl hello.c`

it says `hello.c(1): fatal error C1034: stdio.h: no include path set`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Visual Studio's 'cl' from a normal command line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/84404/608639)

Answer (score 13):

Visual Studio includes a batch file that prepares the environment for you (actually, the Developer Command Prompt calls it under-the-hood).

I've never tried with the Community Edition, but for VS 2017 Professional it is located at `"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars32.bat"`. It may vary if you changed the installation path, of course.

So, all you have to do is to invoke it:

```
call "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars32.bat"
```

Something like following should appear

```
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt v15.7.3
** Copyright (c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
[vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x86'
```

After that you can invoke `cl`, `nmake`, `msbuild` as within cmd.

You can also invoke `vcvarsall.bat x86` instead (the `vcvars32.bat` is just a shortcut for that).

---

You can avoid typing it each time by creating a batch that automatically invokes it and then open a command prompt

```
call "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars32.bat"
cmd
```

And then run that batch instead of cmd.

Another option is to add the `"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\Build\"` to the path so you only have to type `vcvars32.bat` when you need the developer tools.

Comment: Do I need to invoke it everytime I use cmd ?  Isn't there any permanent solution like permanently setting those variables ?

Comment: @keen_learner Yes, you have to invoke it, or just open the Developer Command Prompt instead ;). Another option is to create a batch or add the directory to the path. I've edited the answer to cover those cases.

Comment: If I could upvote this 10 times I would.  Thanks for a great and straightforward answer :-)

Comment: As per the documentation found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line?view=msvc-170#use-the-developer-tools-in-an-existing-command-window) for those looking for it.

Answer (score 4):

Taken from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235639.aspx):

> A *developer command prompt shortcut* automatically sets the correct
>   paths for the compiler and tools, and for any required headers and
>   libraries. You must set these environment values yourself if you use a
>   regular Command Prompt window. For more information, see [Setting the Path and Environment Variables for Command-Line Builds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ccy3wt.aspx).

By running `vcvarsall.bat` in a plain Command Prompt window, you can set environment variables to configure the command line for native 32-bit or 64-bit compilation, or for cross-compilation to x86, x64, or ARM processors.

## To run vcvarsall.bat

1. At the command prompt, change to the Visual C++ installation directory. (The location depends on the system and the Visual Studio installation, but a typical location is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio version\VC\`.) For *example*, enter:

   `cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC"`
2. To configure this Command Prompt window for 32-bit x86 command-line builds, at the command prompt, enter:

   `vcvarsall x86`

The command file sets the required environment variables for the paths to the build tools, libraries, and headers. You can now use this command prompt window to run the command-line compiler and tools.

If you wish to set the include paths etc. yourself, check out https://learn.microsoft.com/nb-no/cpp/build/reference/cl-environment-variables

Comment: Do I need to invoke it everytime I use cmd ? Isn't there any permanent solution like permanently setting those variables ? I was looking for something like setting INCLUDE, LIB, LIBPATH manually

Answer (score 0):

1. open cmd as admin
2. cd "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\Build\ (check for the correct version of VS)
3. while in cmd mode, run vcvars64.bat/vcvars32.bat,
4. now compile ur code for example

   cl main.cpp // will give some warning. to supress it type

   cl /EHs main.cpp